# Get child in maui C#

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mobile, maui

I would like to get a child in net maui C#.

The code looks like this:

XAML:

```
<Border>
   <Border.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer 
         Command="{Binding FollowClickedCommand}" 
         CommandParameter="."/>
   </Border.GestureRecognizers>
          <Label Text="Follow" Margin="10,0"/>
</Border>
```

C#:

```
[RelayCommand]
        async void FollowClicked(Border callerObject)
        {
            
        }
```

The thing I want to do is to get a caller child in C#, in this case, a Label.

Comment: Border has a Content property that contains the child

Comment: I do not know why you are doing this, but I suggest that you stop. If you explain to me what you are trying to achieve in the end, I may suggest better solution than accessing your Visual elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Label)callerObject.Content.GetVisualTreeDescendants().Where(x=> x.GetType() == typeof(Label)).First();
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also note, there is [OfType<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-7.0) : _"Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type."_